# maven archetype:create-from-project does not include other language folder

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I was recently trying to create a maven archetype out of an existing multi module project.
The folder structure was like this:

```
pom.xml
src
  ├───api
  │   │   pom.xml
  │   └───src
  │       ├───main
  │       │   ├───java
  │       │   │    └───api
  │       │   │       MyEntity.java
  │       │   └───resources
  │       │       └───META-INF
  │       │               beans.xml
  └───impl
        │   pom.xml
        └───src
            ├───main
                ├───java
                │     └───impl  
                │           MyImpl.java
                ├───resources
                │   └───META-INF
                │           beans.xml
                │           persistence.xml
                └───sql
                     impl.sql
```

Basically the while process was working properly.
The problem I currently have is that the **sql** folder next to the java folder is not copied into the archetype when performing

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

I already tried to pass this through via archetype.properties without success.

I know that I have the option to adjust the archetype-metadata.xml after the archetype generation, but I would like to generate everything from the sample project without further manual changes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

I don't know why it didn't work yesterday. Today I have no problems creating the sql folder along with the other ones.
The only drawback is that the archetype plugin does not support empty folders, but that is a general issue and is documented in the Maven issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-57

Anyhow thanks and sorry for bothering you guys!